# select's fields function of korma does not reject colums?

Tags: clojure, sqlite, korma, sqlkorma

I play around with clojure and its korma library using an sqlite3 database on windows. I follow an example of the 7web book. It introduces the `select*` function and its friends.

But using the `fields` function adds fields instead of restricting.

```
;; models.clj
(defentity issue
  (entity-fields :id :project_id :title :description :status)
  (has-many comment))

;; repl
test=> (-> (select* issue)
  #_=>     (fields :title)
  #_=>     (as-sql))
"SELECT \"issue\".\"id\", \"issue\".\"project_id\", \"issue\".\"title\", \"issue\".\"description\", \"issue\".\"status\", \"issue\".\"title\" FROM \"issue\""
```

Did i miss anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like mentioned in issue [#251](https://github.com/korma/Korma/issues/251) the reason is the `entity-fields` expression. It defines the default fields for queries. The `fields` function adds more fields to the defaults. Works as designed.

Therefore I removed `entity-fields` within `defentity`.

```
;; models.clj
(defentity issue
  (has-many comment))

;; repl
test=> (-> (select* issue)
  #_=>     (fields :title)
  #_=>     (as-sql))
"SELECT \"issue\".\"title\" FROM \"issue\""
test=> (-> (select* issue)
  #_=>     (as-sql))
"SELECT \"issue\".* FROM \"issue\""
```